# Use array in PHP to compare username/password

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php script which has one username and password:

```
$Username = 'user1';
$Password = 'pass1';

/******************************************************************************/
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])){

    // Clean up the input values 
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); 
        $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); 
    }
    $user = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';
    $report = $_POST['typereport'];

    if ($pass != $Password || $user != $Username) {
        showForm("Wrong Username/Password");
        exit();     
    }
} else {
    showForm();
    exit();
}
```

I would like to make the script more robust, meaning I would like have other username/password so multiple user can login (want it for tracking purposes)

So how do I modify the script so I can use the following for `$Username` and `$Password`:

```
$Username=array("user1","user2","user3");
$Password=array("pass1","pass2","pass3");
```

So the script will always match up with the correct username and password and will allow me to have multiple users?

Comment: Out of curiousity...why aren't you using a database?

Comment: Using PHP because I already have it in place, so trying to make it more robust. Working on the SQL version but trying to decide to go with PDO and mysqli and trying to make it sql-injection proof.

Comment: you want to define usernames and passwords in array, not in database?

Comment: Yes just like the way I have my current script except it will allow multiple username/password.

Comment: Also, you're hashing the passwords, correct? That is, the passwords should not be in plaintext.

Comment: it's not a big thing yet, move your users to database if you really want to make it robust.

Comment: Well right at the moment, it's not being hashed. Just stored in a php file which compares with user entry. But maybe down the line I will implement hashing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use a database.  If you must hardcode, I would use an associative array:

```
<?php
$logins = array(
    'username1' => 'password1',
    'username2' => 'password2',
    'username3' => 'password3',
);

$user = isset($_POST['user']) ? strtolower($_POST['user']) : '';
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

if ( ! isset($logins[$user]) or $logins[$user] != $pass)
{
    showForm("Wrong Username/Password");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: +1 for associative array. I think PHP is lenient regarding the trailing comma in the array, but it's not the best.

Comment: How do I make the username not case sensitive?

Comment: @SiKni8 Keep the array keys all lowercase, then `strtolower` the input